# Promise still pending even though using .then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I am using axios to retrieve data from my BackEnd but the promise is still pending.

I have used .then() even async and await. I am using .then(res => res.data) since i know that every promise has "data" key holding the retrieved data and that after that it will be returned this way. I also binded the function in the constructor!

```
async getTrackInfo() {
  return await axios.get('http://localhost:60231/api/values')
    .then(res => res.data);
};


componentDidMount() {
  const data = this.getTrackInfo();
  console.log(data);

  this.setState({
    tracks: data
  });
}
```

But unfortunately, it returns undefined.

Comment: You need `const data = await this.getTrackInfo();`

Comment: `async` functions always return a promise. Promises are a standard way to manage asynchronous operations. `async`/`await` gives you procedural style syntax to manage them with. They don't stop asynchronous operations from being asynchronous

Comment: @ChrisG - That will error. `componentDidMount` isn't `async`

Comment: @Quentin pretty sure the instruction to change `componentDidMount()` to `async` was implicit in Chris's comment...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following code would work:-

```
async getTrackInfo() {
  return await axios.get('http://localhost:60231/api/values')
    .then(res => res.data);
};


async componentDidMount() { // Make this function async
  const data = await this.getTrackInfo(); // add await here
  console.log(data);

  this.setState({
    tracks: data
  });
}
```

Comment: To use `await`, you have to make the function (in this case, `componentDidMount`) `async`.

Comment: A small nitpick, the `await` in `return await` is superfluous. Might as well remove `async` from `getTrackInfo()` and `return axios...`. It will do the same thing.